# Extra Space being added when creating the query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an Update query for products in which the products skus are coming from the array. This is the query I am trying to create.

```
$first_query = "UPDATE `product` SET `price` = ".$discount_small[$i]." WHERE `sku` LIKE '".$product_numbers[$i]."'";
```

When I print this query into the browser, this is what it gives...

```
UPDATE `product` SET `price` = 11.02 WHERE `sku` LIKE '427 '
```

If you note there is an extra space at the end of 427. I have checked my array, space is not there in the array. When I print that sku seperately i just get 427.

Any ideas why it is adding that extra space?

Comment: the original value has this white space at the end, use `trim()`

Comment: Shouldn't you also be doing `\`price\` = "11.02"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the space is inside the `$product_numbers[$i]` value, try with `rtrim($product_numbers[$i])`, [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) removes the space at the end of the string if no second parameter is specified.